# Why do I need to reboot Windows 10 when installing a webcam?

Tags: windows-10

Since I'm just using USB, why would I need to reboot after installing a Logitech Webcam? Does USB not support hot loading/unloading of drivers?

Comment: It does;  What exactly is being displayed?  Can you provide a screenshot of that prompt?

Comment: You probably don't need a reboot.  Did you run the Logitech installer or simply let windows install the drivers?  Installer programmers are lazy (I know.. I was one for 5 years).  They also tend to be juniors and don't check the actual conditions required for a reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB is hot plugable `once a device's drivers are installed`. This is especially true if you are using vendor supplied software that adds services which run at start to support additional features and run from the system tray. If you do not care about those features you can probably skip the reboot, but they will be present the next time you reboot.

Each USB port on your system is likely on a different internal USB 'hub' The driver part which doesn't need a restart to be functional will probably claim it needs one the first time  you connect the device to a different hub because software will treat each new device location as a new devices. The software installer isn't smart. You should just get this out of the way now, and choose "reboot later" for each of the successive prompts

If windows already has drivers which support the device, then you likely wont be prompted for a reboot then either, but you may not get all the features, or you may just get a bunch of bloat from the manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks - I thought even the underlying drivers could be hot plugged based on USB (there'd be some non-rebooting kernel attachment mechanism, similar to ld on Linux), but thanks!

Comment: The way Generic Drivers work is that The USB device advertises the services that it supports when you attach it. If the Operating system has a driver or in the case of linux, a module which supports the generic feature, for instance Storage or HID for USB drives.then the generic functionality will work and no reboot is needed. For the webcam the vendor chose to not use a standard device type as a result generic drivers wont work. if you have windows search for and download `USBDevView` and you will get an enumerated list of every usb device ever attached to your system.

Comment: One further thing, with Windows you are safest treating it like an autistic child. Be amazed when it does something you don't expect, but don't assume that anything you `think should happen` is the way it will happen. Windows isn't an advanced learning platform. Its responses are coded by multiple vendors and the manufacturer programmers. based on settings they tell the system to request.